# Estimating a Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ are two Lebesgue integrable functions on $[0,+\infty)$ such that $$|f(s)-g(s)|\leq w(Ms)\qquad \forall s\geq 0,$$ where $w:[0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty)$ is a non decreasing function such that $w$ is continuous at $t=0$ and $w(0)=0$ and $M>0$ is fixed.

Is it true that for all $t\geq 0$ $$\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds=\int_{0}^{t}g(s)ds +o(t)$$ where $o(t)$ indicates a function $h(t)$ such that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{|h(t)|}{t}=0$ and $|h(t)|\leq w(Mt)t$?

Can anyone prove/disprove it?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You have two functions $g$ in your question. Are they really supposed to be the same?

Comment: You are right, they are different. I have fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what role $M$ is supposed to play. Take $M = 1$.

All you need is monotonicity of the integral.
If $0 \le s \le t$ then $f(s) - g(s) \le \omega(s) \le \omega(t)$ so that

$$ \int_0^t f(s) \, ds - \int_0^t g(s) \, ds \le \int_0^t \omega(s) \, ds \le t \omega(t).$$

Similarly
$$\int_0^t g(s) \, ds - \int_0^t f(s) \, ds \le \int_0^t \omega(s) \, ds \le t \omega(t).$$
Write $$h(t) = \int_0^t f(s) \, ds - \int_0^t g(s) \, ds.$$ Then you have
$$|h(t)| \le t \omega(t)$$ and
$$\frac{|h(t)|}{t} \le \omega(t) \to 0 \quad \text{as} \quad t \to 0^+.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, the role of $M$ is irrelevant. I'm trying to prove something different from this, if you please can have a look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102743/estimating-a-lebesgue-integral-and-taylors-formula